# Use 1 View For 2 Tabs Of A UITabBarController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uistoryboard

I am looking to have a UITabBarController with 4 tabs, two of these tabs are linked in storyboard to their respective view controllers; however the third and fourth tab I want to re-use the same view controller as they are more or less identical. The problem is I can only link the UITabBarController to the view controller once and therefore cannot create the fourth tab?

Answer (score 0):

So as I didn't get an answer that could use storyboard within the time frame I had hoped, I had to do it programatically; which for anyone who is wondering, I did like this.

```
let master = UIStoryboard(name: "iPad", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle()).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("navDir") as! UINavigationController
        let detail = UIStoryboard(name: "iPad", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle()).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("navPro") as! UINavigationController

        viewControllers = [master, detail]
```